# Influxdb storage folder [windows]

Tags: influxdb

I am trying to check size of db created in influxdb. Where can I find storage folder, or if it is distributed in many places what is the best method to measure size of my db ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Note:** Answer below is for macOS/Linux and was provided before the [windows] tag was added.

In the [Data section of the Influx documentation](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.2/administration/config/#data), it is stated:

> **dir = '/var/lib/influxdb/data'**
> The directory where InfluxDB stores the data. This directory may be changed.
> Note: The default directory for OS X installations is `/Users/<username>/.influxdb/data`

It is safe to say that this directory contains the base persisted file storage of the database.

As mentioned in the docs, the default data storage directory can be overriden by changing the`INFLUXDB_DATA_DIR` environment variable.

Specifically for Windows you will probably find the data path in the **influxdb.conf** file.

However, this directory does not include the meta data for the Influx instance, like users, databases, retention policies etc., nor stuff like the WAL (write-ahead-log), cache, logs and others. If you're interested in this, the earlier mentioned docs provide insight into this as well.

Comment: This does not answer the question for Windows distributions [on influxdb 1.7]. The data path that you find in the conf file will only be for linux. See Mark Wragg's answer

Answer (score 14):

In the default configurations for Windows, the data is stored in the directory `c:\Users\<username>\.influxdb\data\`.

EDIT:
I couldn't change that from the config file, but setting `INFLUXDB_DATA_DIR` environment variable can do the trick.

Answer (score 8):

If you are running InfluxDB as a Windows Service and that service is running as the local system account, you will find the .influxdb\data directory here by default:

```
C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.influxdb\data
```

Comment: Yes I am using nssm.exe to run InfluxDB as a Windows Service on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard on 2019 Feb and the InfluxDB files are there.

Answer (score 2):

Update `influxdb.conf` file with the location you want.

Open `cmd`

`Cd` to the path

Run `influxd.exe -config influxdb.conf`